# Send HTTP response to client without having request always

Tags: java, http, httpresponse, servlet-3.0

My `Java`server application(`Servlet`) receive a service request (`HTTP`) from client and then it should respond to the client in fixed interval time.

How can I send `HTTP` response every minute to client without having a `HTTP` request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere
or Comet/WebSockets

Comment: My client is not a html client. It is a java http connection. So I can't use jsp/html/ajax. can comet use without javascript? if yes I would like to see an example.